# Creating new value based on atom and map functions

Tags: clojure

I would like to iterate over values in atom in order to create new collection (but without updating an `atom`).
I have next definition of atom:
`let [st (atom {})]` and now I would like to do sth like this:

```
(-> (seq (keys @st))
    (map (fn [key] [key (get @st key)]))))
```

Provided example is simplified, but even in such situation I have problems.
I am receving next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: example.test$init$reify__2273$fn__2275
        at clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom(RT.java:505)
        at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:486)
        at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
        at clojure.core$map$fn__4245.invoke(core.clj:2551)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
        at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
        at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
        at clojure.core$print_sequential.invoke(core_print.clj:46)
        at clojure.core$fn__5457.invoke(core_print.clj:147)
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
        at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:3392)
        at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3404)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$print.doInvoke(core.clj:3449)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$print_str.doInvoke(core.clj:4391)
        ...
```

Comment: use ->> instead of -> (map expects the sequence as last argument, not first)

Comment: You are right! It is extremely silly question - too much coding for today.

Comment: I know it's not the real code but you should not deref an atom twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "thread first" macro (`->`) inserts the value returned by the previous expression into the second position of the next expression - immediately after the function. In your example this causes the parameters to the `map` function call to be the wrong way round (the function should be first, the collection second). That's what the exception is about.

In this case you should use the "thread last" macro (`->>`) to insert the value into the last position of the next function call:

```
(let [st (atom {:a 1 :b 2})]
  (->> (seq (keys @st))
       (map (fn [key] [key (get @st key)]))))
;; returns: ([:b 2] [:a 1])
```

However this can be simplified to the following, since a map can be directly traversed as a seq, with each element being a vector of key and value, just as you're trying to do:

```
(let [st (atom {:a 1 :b 2})]
  (seq @st))
;; returns: ([:b 2] [:a 1])
```

If you're looking to transform these values as you go, you can also take advantage of [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)), for example with a call to `map`:

```
(let [st (atom {:a 1 :b 2})]
  (map (fn [[k v]] [k (+ v 1)]) @st))
;; returns: ([:b 3] [:a 2])
```

So the key and value are extracted for you using that function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using just `@st` is fine - the **value** of the atom is immutable. If you will modify the atom, previously retrieved value cannot be affected (assuming that you're using Clojure data structures). To illustrate:

```
(def a (atom {:a 1})) ; => #'user/a
(def b @a) ; => #'user/b
(reset! a {:a 2}) ; => {:a 2}
b ; => {:a 1}
```

Comment: I did not add code for adding elements because I was thinking that it does not change anything

Comment: @baju Removed first part - it's true, that replacing `->` to `->>` fixes exception in your example. Still, there is no need of manual data copying.